# Do i need a countdown latch with parallel stream to ensure thread waits?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a tree structure of objects.  Currently, the head of the tree iterates over each child node and that in turn then iterates over it's child nodes.  This is all done on a single thread, but each branch can be done in parallel and the parent just needs to return when all child nodes have completed their task.

I was planning on using a parallel stream to do this and just wanted to ask whether this is an ok approach.  I also wonder whether I need to use a countdown latch as shown below to stop the thread progressing until all child worker threads have completed.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(list size)
childObjects.parallelStream().forEach(child -> {
  child.doSomeTask(data);
  latch.countDown();
})

countDown.await();
```

Comment: No, the `forEach` is blocking - it will return once it's done.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Would you say it was an acceptable use of the parallel stream approach or would you use an executor service?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Are you doing independant operations that don't mutate external state on some data? Are you doing something else? This question is far too broad.

Comment: Fair point.  Each operation is independent and no mutation of shared state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same approach parallelStream with countdownlatch, later realized the parallelStream.foreach blocking call itself suffice no need of countdownlatch. adding countdownlatch doesn't add any value here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [RecursiveTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) or [RecursiveAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) in conjunction with [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool). Use `fork` method to produce subtask for child nodes and `join` method to wait until they are finished.